# Can a task re-schedule itself with APScheduler?

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I am trying to set up a delayed task task whose timing will depend on several parameters (either passed to it or obtained from a redis database).

the pseudocode would look like this:

```
def main():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(delayed_task, 
                      id=task_id,
                      next_run_time=somedate,
                      args=(task_id, some_data))
    scheduler.start()
    do_something_else()


def delayed_task(id, passed_data):
    rd = connect_to_redis()
    redis_data = rd.fetch_data(id)
    publish_data(passed_data, redis_data)

    updated_run_time = parse(redis_data)
    #obtain a scheduler object here
    scheduler.modify_job(id, next_run_time=updated_run_time)
```

The question is the following: is there a way to access the scheduler from a task?
The scheduler cannot be passed as parameter to the task, as this will raise

`TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`

For the same reason, I can't put all this in a class and have it called a method since the arguments of the method include `self`, which is the class containing the scheduler, and will thus result in the same issue.

Is it possible to regain an instance of the scheduler from outside, like I can generate a new connexion to redis?